# Allocating memory through a pointer array of objects and set their names with method

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am doing a memory allocation exercise using a pointer array. The task is to create an array of 26 objects. Then loop through the alphabet and for each item in the array, use a setName() method to set a name, (e.g. name each item with each letter of the alphabet and churn it out), for the alphabet/object at that index in the array.

Then loop through the array again with another loop and print all the names (with a getName() method).  I've already written the code (OO). When I run it, I get a debug assertion fail! error.  I can't figure out the moment what the error is in my code.  I know there are easier ways to cout the alphabet by, for example, just using a for loop, but I'm trying to see  how a loop and a pointer array work together and the use of constructors and destructors.  This is my code:

```
class Alphabet {
private:
    string name;
public:
    Alphabet() {
        cout << "Alphabet created" << endl;
    }
    Alphabet(const Alphabet& other) :name(other.name) {
        cout << "Alphabet created by copying" << endl;
    }
    ~Alphabet() {
        cout << "destructor called" << endl;
    }

    void setName(string name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    void speak() const {
        cout << "My name is: " << name << endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    {
        char ALPH = 'a';
        string name(4, ALPH);
        Alphabet* alphabet1[4];

        for (int n = 0; n < ALPH; n++) {

            alphabet1[n] = new Alphabet;
            cout << alphabet1[n] << endl;
        }

        alphabet1[4]->setName("a");
        alphabet1[4]->speak();

        for (int n = 0; n < ALPH; n++) {
            delete alphabet1[n];
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Tried it but the program still stops working

Answer (score 0):

There are several flaws in your code, I will list them mixed up with some information that might enlighten you:

- if `ALPH` is interpreted numerically, the `int` value for `'a'` will be used. This is a number like 63 or something; consequently your `for` loop goes out of bounds
- `alphabet1[4]` refers to the fifth pointer of `alphabet1`; however, you only have four entries here
- `string name(4, ALPH);` creates "aaaa", is this your intention?

Correct those bugs and it should run fine. If you want to map a `char` to a `string` or some class, you could use `std::map<char, string>` or `std::map<char, SomeClass>;` however, this might have some overhead, there are cleverer solutions

Comment: ALPH is not interpreted numerically I believe.  Just did a cout before,inside and after the loop and it's still 'a'. I don't want to get aaaa as you might've gathered, I'm still trying to get string name(4, ALPH) to go a, b, c...

Comment: It is not interpreted that way when using `cout` but it is when comparing it to an int which is done at `n < ALPH` in your for loop

Comment: .Im still confused as to how the for loop and the array work together to produce the result after increasing the number of items to 26.

Comment: aha, I see what you mean

Comment: If you want to stick with your array-based solution, you would need a mapping from characters to numbers. 'a' should become 0, 'b' should become 1 and so on. You can use `int index = letter - 'a';` to accomplish exactly this and then use `alphabet1[index]` to access all the letters. Your loop should simply iterate the interval [0;26)